# Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.Long' in your configuration

Tags: java

I've created this `Component`, but I always get an error with the **Long** **of userId**. I do not know how I can fix it so that it does not show me the error :

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in es.udc.tfgproject.backend.model.services.ScheduledTask required a bean of type 'java.lang.Long' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.Long' in your configuration.
```

> Failed to load ApplicationContext

Code:

```
public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    private Long userId;
    private Timer time;

    ScheduledTask(Long userId, Timer time) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userDao.findById(userId);
        if (!userOptional.isPresent()) {
            time.cancel();
        } else {

            BigDecimal globalBalance = userOptional.get().getGlobalBalance();
            userOptional.get().setGlobalBalance(globalBalance.subtract(Constantes.RELIVRY_COMPANY_FEE));
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks

----------------------------------------UPDATE----------------------

Now i got this in my Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    //Other beans

    @Bean
    ScheduledTask scheduledTask() {
        return new ScheduledTask(1L, new Timer());
    }

}
```

Deleted @Component

But now, is throwing me this error:

```
Exception in thread "Timer-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at es.udc.tfgproject.backend.model.services.ScheduledTask.run(ScheduledTask.java:29)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

That makes reference to:

```
Optional<User> userOptional = userDao.findById(userId);
```

Comment: What do you *want* the values of `userId` and `time` to be on `ScheduledTask`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are annotated a class with @Component, spring will auto detect this for dependency injection.

For your `ScheduledTask` bean there are two dependencies. They are type `Long` and `Timer`. When spring try to inject these dependencies, spring won't able to find any beans match to these two.

What you can do is something like this.

Remove your @Component annotation from your `ScheduledTask` class.

```
public class ScheduledTask extends TimerTask {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    private Long userId;
    private Timer time;

    ScheduledTask(Long userId, Timer time) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.time = time;
        time.schedule(this, 1000, 7890000); // this will add a one second of a initial delay and 3 months of a period delay
    }
    // other relevant code
}
```

Then create the bean inside a configuration class. Like this, (Make sure you update userId accordingly)

```
@Configuration
public class YourConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ScheduledTask scheduledTask() {
        return new ScheduledTask(1L, new Timer());
    }
}
```

### Method 2

You can create a cron job using @Scheduler

Update your `ScheduledTask` like this. You no longer need `Timer` or `TimerTask`.

```
public class ScheduledTask {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    private Long userId;

    public ScheduledTask(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/1 * 1/1 * *")
    public void run() {
        // your logic here
    }
}
```

Create `ScheduledTask` bean

```
@Bean
ScheduledTask scheduledTask() {
    return new ScheduledTask(1L); // make sure to change userId accordingly
}
```

You can generate cron expressions [here](http://www.cronmaker.com/?1)

Comment: Hi, i change that, but now is throwing me this error in the update above.

Comment: To be honest I don't have slightest idea what are you trying to do here.. Anyway I can see that error is in this line "Optional<User> userOptional = userDao.findById(userId);". Only reason I can think for this is you have removed @Autowired annotation from "private UserDao userDao;" this line. Second thing is how did "run()" method executed when you don't have scheduled your time task using timer. Is this "ScheduledTask" class is complete?

Comment: Yes, is completed. And i don't remove @Autowired. What I'm trying to do with this code is to substract periodically 120 USD. I have this timer, that execute the run method in ScheduledTask every three months. And in the method from my service I initialize ScheduledTask, that extends from TimerTask.

Comment: How did you set this timer to run in every three months?

Comment: With Timer.schedule(TimerTask, delay, period)

Comment: Check my updated answer. You can find a alternative method as well if you are interested.